Problem with def function with astype method
i try to iterate in my df.dtypes and when dtypes == 'float' i wanna change it to int.
df = pd.DataFrame({'TotalRevenue':[300,9000,1000,750,500,2000,0,600,50,500], 
                   'Date':['2016-12-02' for i in range(10)], 
                   'SaleCount':[10,100,30,35,20,100,0,30,2,20], 
                   'shops':['S3','S2','S1','S5','S4','S8','S6','S7','S9','S10']})

def myFunc(df):
  for el in range(0, len(df.dtypes)):
    if df.dtypes[el] == 'float64':
      df = df.astype({df.columns[el] : 'int64'})
  return df.dtypes

myFunc(df)      

and everythink work fine, code return me right dtypes
TotalRevenue     int64
Date            object
SaleCount        int64
shops           object
dtype: object

But when i write df.dtypes in my note, nothing change
TotalRevenue    float64
Date             object
SaleCount         int64
shops            object
dtype: object


Please explain write  df.dtypes in my note. Also add the code of how you get the data.

Firstly, there are no float values (and so no column float dtypes) in the data you present. But assuming there was in say TotalRevenue then you cannot set to int64 dtype using your approach (you are not using the values returned from the function and if you did use this to set dtypes then it would cause an warning error). What you need to do is select the columns with the 'wrong' dtypes and change these:
Using a mask:
m = df.select_dtypes('float64').columns

df[m] = df[m].astype('int64')

or if you wanted to use a loop:
for column in df.columns:
    if df[column].dtype == 'float64':
        df[column] = df[column].astype('int64')


I suppose you're encountering a common issue that arises when modifying a DataFrame within a function. When you modify the DataFrame within the function myFunc, the changes don't persist outside of the function scope unless you explicitly return the modified DataFrame and assign it back to the original variable.
Here's a modification that might work
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'TotalRevenue':[300,9000,1000,750,500,2000,0,600,50,500], 
                   'Date':['2016-12-02' for i in range(10)], 
                   'SaleCount':[10,100,30,35,20,100,0,30,2,20], 
                   'shops':['S3','S2','S1','S5','S4','S8','S6','S7','S9','S10']})

def myFunc(df):
    for el in range(0, len(df.dtypes)):
        if df.iloc[el].dtypes == 'float64':
            df = df.astype({df.columns[el]: 'int64'})
    return df

df = myFunc(df)
print(df.dtypes)

output
   TotalRevenue     int64
   Date            object
   SaleCount        int64
   shops           object
   dtype: object

